# Is it possible to specify groups from two different inventory files for an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My playbook (`/home/user/Ansible/dist/playbooks/test.yml`):

```
- hosts: regional_clients
  tasks:
    - shell: /export/home/user/ansible_scripts/test.sh
      register: shellout
    - debug: var=shellout
- hosts: web_clients
  tasks:
    - shell: /var/www/html/webstart/release/ansible_scripts/test.sh 
      register: shellout
    - debug: var=shellout
    - command: echo catalina.sh start
      register: output
    - debug: var=output
```

The `[regional_clients]` group is specified in `/home/user/Ansible/webproj/hosts` and the `[web_clients]` group is specified in `/home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts`.

Is there a way I could make the above work? Currently, running the playbook will fail since neither `[regional_clients]` or `[web_clients]` are defined in the default inventory file `/home/user/Ansible/dist/hosts`.

Comment: In my playbook, I want to specify the group [regional_clients] from /home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts for one play, and for the second play, I want to specify the group [web_clients] from /home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts.

Comment: This is because the inventory files /home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts and /home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts are maintained by other groups and are constantly changing, otherwise I would just define both groups in my default inventory file (/home/user/Ansible/dist/hosts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /home/user/Ansible/webproj/hosts /home/user/Ansible/regions/hosts
```

and call it as a [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) in Ansible:

```
ansible-playbook -i my_script test.yml
```

---

<sup>This question, however, looks to me like a problem with your organisation, not a technical one. If your environment is so complex and maintained by different parties, then use some kind of configuration database (and a dynamic inventory in Ansible which would retrieve the data), instead of individual files in user's paths.</sup>